# Random Quote generator - How can i set the setInterval after every page load or page refresh?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, pageload, page-refresh

I have created a random quote generator which runs the quote itself in every 12 sec. However i want it to change in 2 second after every page load or page refresh .

```
function changeQuote()
{
   getQuotes();
   setInterval(getQuotes, 12000);
}
```

Comment: this is simple, change time from 12000 ms to 2000 ms

Comment: I mean first time it should change the quote in 2 sec and then in 12 second. @kritikaTalwar

Answer (score 1):

You want it to be called 2 seconds after page load - then every 12 seconds after that?

Have you tried something like this?

```js
function getQuotes() {
  // This is the function that gets your quotes
  console.log("Fetched quotes", new Date());
}

function firstRun() {
  getQuotes();
  setInterval(getQuotes, 12000);
}

setTimeout(firstRun, 2000);
console.log("Page loaded", new Date());
```

This will (2 seconds after page load) call `firstRun` which gets the quotes - but also sets up our interval for the next runs. You can see it in action by pressing the "Run code snippet" button.